# Beamer Warsaw: how to have a rounded shadow?

Tags: beamer, shadows

When I put the option `\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}`, there is this fatal error :

> LaTeX Error: Option clash for package beamerinnerthemerounded.

When commenting on this line, `%\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}` the shadow is square!

The code:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610,10pt]{beamer} % Présentation générale et mise en page
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{default}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
%\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertframenavigationsymbol}
\author{By me}
\institute{Junior High School}
\title {Some }

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The result :

[image: beamer-shadow-rounded]

**Edit: Copy of the beginning of the log file**

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6800 64-bit) (preloaded format=latex 2018.8.31)  31 AUG 2018 19:06
entering extended mode
**./test-dev.tex
(test-dev.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamer.cls"
Document Class: beamer 2018/08/22 v3.51 A class for typesetting presentations
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasemodes.sty"
```

Comment: Your beamer version seems to be outdated. With the code as it is in your question, I get a rounded shadow:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/UptIi.png And you don't need `\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}`, this is what `Warsaw` already loads.

Comment: @samcarter I updated MikTeX yesterday, how is that possible?

Comment: Can you add `\listfiles` to your preamble and look into your log file which beamer version you have? Current one is 3.51

Comment: @samcarter I got version 3.51!

Comment: How are you compiling? pdflatex or some other engine?

Comment: And which pdf viewer do you use?

Comment: @samcarter I use adobe reader.

Comment: I see you are compiling with latex. This can be a problem for the transparency. Can you switch to pdflatex?

Comment: @samcarter When compiling with pdflatex, there is the same error!

Comment: Could you please add the complete .log file for the compilation with pdflatex?

Comment: @samcarter Okay, the full code is too long, the editor won't let it be written in its entirety. How can I do that?

Comment: You could try https://pastebin.com/

Comment: @samcarter It is here (compiled with pdflatex) https://pastebin.com/X8LRFaEh

Comment: I guess I'm out of ideas. I compared package versions with mine and the seem to all match. One last try: remove `\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}` from your code so that it compiles without error and then compile again with pdflatex

Comment: @samcarter By commenting the code and compiling with pdfLaTeX, the shadow is rounded and it compiles without problem ! I don't understand anything at all.

Comment: Good to hear it works now! I think the previous attempt to compile with pdflatex did not give the desired result was because there was still an error and no correct pdf was generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different problems involved:

- **If you have beamer version 3.51:**  compiling with `latex` and subsequently converting to pdf does not work well for elements which contain transparency. Workaround: compile directly to pdf with pdflatex or use one of the other engines.
- As long as there is an error message, there is also no point in looking at what might or might not be valid pdf. Luckily the error can easily be solved by removing the line `\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}` -- it is not necessary at all because the Warsaw theme already loads it with the option `shadow=true`

Comment: Now I have another incomprehensible error: this document which is very long (24 slides) and contains many images (57), tikz code and ocg layers...
I compiled it a week ago on my laptop with Windows 10 without problem and now on the other desktop with Windows 10 it no longer compiles completely.
I don't know how to do this anymore! I wonder if it might be a Windows 10 problem?

Comment: @AndréC Can you show the error message you get?

Comment: line 1 Package etex Warning: Extended allocation already in use.

Comment: @AndréC On the first glance this looks like a warning. But can you copy the complete message from the log file somewhere which preserves lines breaks, e.g. into your question?

Comment: The log is here https://pastebin.com/rdMfejGp

Comment: @AndréC This is only a warning. I would not be too worried about that. That the log suddenly stops looks strange.

Comment: The problem is that the pdf is not produced!

Comment: @AndréC Try to temporarily comment the slide with the image `toit-Gray_hotel_de_ville`. Does is compile now?

Comment: @AndréC Can you come to https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends  Maybe it is easier to talk there.

Answer (score 1):

Try `\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}`:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610,10pt]{beamer} % Présentation générale et mise en page
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{default}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertframenavigationsymbol}
\author{By me}
\institute{Junior High School}
\title {Some }

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

This compiles with no errors.

---

The reason is that the [`Warsaw` theme](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/theme/beamerthemeWarsaw.sty) declares the following:

```
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
```

So loading `\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}` would lead to option clash. However, to be honest, you don’t need to specify `\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}` or `\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}`.

BTW, if I commented out `\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}`, the shadows still *are rounded*. You probably need to check if your `beamer` class is updated properly.

Comment: The shadow is not rounded, but there is no more error.